# (Android) change text size of a child-view of spinner

Tags: java, android, spinner

I use the following code to access the child view of spinner and then change the font size of the text. Unfortunately, I cannot change the size of the text while I can get the text of the child view of the spinner. Could anyone tell me the problem below?

```
SpinnerAdapter temp=spinner.getAdapter();//get adapter from spinner
TextView text_in_spinner=(TextView)temp.getDropDownView(1, null, null);//get all view at position 1

text_in_spinner.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,15);//set text size
Log.v("view text",(String)text_in_spinner.getText());//get text
```

Comment: Was my answer helpful to you?

Answer (score -1):

You can implement a custom adapter:

```
private static class MySpinnerAdapter implements SpinnerAdapter {
    private SpinnerAdapter mAdapter;

    public DropDownAdapter(SpinnerAdapter adapter) {
        this.mAdapter = adapter;
    }

    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = mAdapter.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
        (TextView)v.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,15);
    }
}
```

So you change

```
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

to

```
spinner.setAdapter(new MySpinnerAdapter(adapter));
```

Another option is to specify a custom layout for the dropdown items. Supposing you are using `ArrayAdapter` like in the [doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html), you can specify your own layout resource instead of `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item`, so you can specify the text size in the layout xml file and don't have to assign it manually.